Removing PyCharm's output from its console
I found bunch of solutions but PyCharm changes its menu from version to version so old solutions do not work for me.
Mine is PyCharm 2024.2.3 (Community Edition) on Ubuntu 20.04
When I run anything in PyCharm, 2 extra lines are included in the output: 1 at beginning and 1 at the end.
How do I get rid of them? 
Example:
/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/astro/example/HelloWorld.py 
Hello World

Process finished with exit code 0


This question is similar to: How to hide path location in Run Window in Pycharm?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Well, it does not remove particular lines, only covers them. It would also cover lines in middle of output if I had such.  Second solution (plugin) does not look in my pycharm as it is described by @multigoodverse.
My goal is to have it removed so I can freely ctrl+a, ctrl+c, ctrl+v to another tool. I know there is a 'Save console output to file' which additionally shows even more ("Console output is saving to:  .......") on pycharm's output.
I am just trying to find handy way of copy-paste, but I am not happy seeing JetBrains forgot to implement such thing ;(

Why not run your code from the command line and pipe the output to a text file from which you can copy/paste? E.g. python HelloWorld.py > hello_world.txt
